# Clean Wordpress-Like URLs with PHP and Apache

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, url, seo

I want to know how to make clean url with php and apache. Like wordpress does.

For example, in wordpress there's only one file index.php, which handles all the urls. i want to know how it does that?

like:

**example.com/about** or **http://www.example.com/about/** give the index.php some kind of information to generate the page.

there are alot of other resources on the web that can generate .htaccess but there are file specific only like:

**example.com/products/cat1/10** goes to **example.com/products.php?c=cat1&id=10**

i don't want that... i want all the page requests to end on giving some kind of information to php and then php generating the page...

What will be the .htaccess code and how will php handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the front controller pattern. There's a lot of directions you can take with this, but if you do a quick [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20front%20controller) you'll find a lot of places to make a start.

Answer (score 0):

Just redraw the page using php then redraw your url's using apache

Comment: I won't vote down but I simply can't see how your answer is helpful. "Redraw the page using php" can be interpreted in so many ways.

Comment: "Redraw the page using php"  can't be interpreted in many ways, it just stand for the main thing php does: redraws the page.

Comment: Erm what? PHP doesn't 'redraw' anything. How the heck do you even 'draw' stuff? Do you mean templating or including the pages using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Whoa! It is SO bloated question. There are plenties of ways to do what you want. Basically you should follow one simple pattern:

1. You pass the `query string` to `index.php` (only this file will handle all queries, so I'd suggest you follow [`MVC pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) in this case)
2. In your `index.php` you analyze the `query string` (dispatching), so you know what you should do (part of your query string should point somehow thich controller and action is being invoked).
3. You pass (parsed) query parameters to some function (which is `action` in MVC) which can be method of a class (pretty common approach when class is `controller` containing methods-actions)

You should write your own Url-Mapper so it can know which controller is needed and which action should be performed basing on query string.

BTW, why don't you just delve into WP's code if you really like its URL management?